# Python, insert record into database from JOIN statement

Tags: python, sql, database, join

I'm trying to write combined table data into a new table for a timing system I'm working on.

The following SQL works in PHPMyAdmin.:

```
INSERT
INTO
    results(
        firstName,
        lastName,
        raceNumber,
        raceTime
    )
SELECT
    s.firstName,
    s.lastName,
    s.raceNumber,
    h.time
FROM
    runners s
INNER JOIN
    chipData hp
ON
    s.raceNumber = hp.bandID
INNER JOIN
    readings h
ON
    hp.tagId = h.tagId
WHERE
    hp.tagId = 123456
LIMIT 1
```

However, if I add this into a Python statement as follows, it doesn't work:

```
db = connect()
    cur = db.cursor()
    cur.execute("""INSERT INTO results( firstName, lastName, raceNumber, raceTime ) SELECT s.firstName, s.lastName, s.raceNumber, h.time FROM runners s INNER JOIN chipData hp ON s.raceNumber = hp.bandID INNER JOIN readings h ON hp.tagId = h.tagId WHERE hp.tagId = %s LIMIT 1""", (123456)
    db.commit()
    db.close()
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Sorry, close bracket is at the end of the execute statement.